# 'Weighted sample' from overlapping categories

Tags: python, random, statistics

I wish to write a function, that will sample from various (potentially overlapping) categories \$C_1, C_2, \ldots C_k\$, such that the sampled values are in the ratio \$r_1:r_2:\ldots: r_k\$ or as close to that ratio as is possible. The categories may well (and most of the time definitely will) overlap.

The sample size is typically quite small (less than 100) and the number of categories is also generally small (no more than 10). The size of the categories may well be very large typically of order \$10^5\$, but could potentially be of order \$10^7\$ or 8. The amount of overlap can also be significant (even up to one category being completely contained within another category).

**What I want to know**

At the moment it seems like a fairly large function, for a (on the face of it) simple idea. Can the function be made cleaner and more efficient / faster?

It does not run particularly slowly at the moment, but I am reasonably new to programming, and would like to know if I am missing any obvious ways of making this more efficient.

**Further Particulars about the problem**

If the size of a particularly category is small, and the total sample size is sufficently large, that the entire category would be used up, then the remaining 'weight' should be divided amongst the other catgeories in the initial ratio. 
For example, suppose \$C_1, C_2,\$ and \$C_3\$ are of size 4, 100 and 100 respectively (and are also non-intersecting), and I want a sample of size 60 in the ratio \$1:2:3\$. I can't take 10 values from \$C_1\$ since there are only 4. So I will take the remaining 6 unassigned values, and split them in the ratio \$2:3\$, meaning there should be 22.4 values from \$C_2\$ and 33.6 values from \$C_3\$.

(I don't mind how these fractional values are assigned, and at the moment, am simply rounding up the larger values). The final result should be 4, 22 and 34 values from \$C_1, C_2\$ and \$C_3\$ respectively. (This is, again, assuming these sets are non-intersecting - which is not the case in the general problem).

I appreciate there is a certain amount of ambiguity about what I mean by "as close as possible to that ratio" although am happy to accept any reasonable interpretation of that statement if it will make the process easier/more efficient.

At the moment, I am counting any element chosen in the sample, as only 'counting' towards one category. The reason for this can be best explained by the following sample:

Suppose \$C_1 = \lbrack A,B,C,D\rbrack\$ and \$C_2 = \lbrack C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L\rbrack \$. I desire 6 values in the ratio \$1:2\$.  If I choose C and D from category 1, and I then choose 4 different values from \$C_2\$, the ratio will become \$1:3\$ not \$1:2\$). The only way I can choose values to make the ratio \$1:2\$ is to never pick C and D - which seems to sacrifice too much 'randomness' for the sake of getting the ratio 'close to the given ratio'.

```
from random import sample

def weighted_sample(categories, weights, desired_sample_size):
    """Returns a weighted sample from the categories in the ratios given:

    categories - a list of lists, each sublist is a category.
    weights - a list of numbers of equal len to categories
    desired_sample_size - the length of the returned list.

    If a category is 'used up' any remaining weight from that category is
    reapportioned in the ratio of the remaining weights. If an item is in more
    than one category, it will be chosen only once.
    """

    # Calculate quantity to sample from each category
    sum_of_weights = sum(weights)
    normalised_weights = [weight / sum_of_weights for weight in weights]
    sample_sizes = [n_weight * desired_sample_size
                    for n_weight in normalised_weights]

    datasets = [set(d) for d in categories]  # copy categories
    results = set()

    while len(results) < desired_sample_size:
        overflow_sum = 0  # For when a category is used up, and has left over
        unassigned_values = []  # fractional quantities still to be assigned

        for index, sample_size in enumerate(sample_sizes):
            dataset_size = len(datasets[index])
            if sample_size >= dataset_size:
                sampled_values = set(datasets[index])
                unassigned_values.append(0)
                overflow_sum += sample_size - dataset_size
            else:
                sampled_values = set(sample(datasets[index], int(sample_size)))
                unassigned_values.append(sample_size-int(sample_size))
            results |= sampled_values
            for d in datasets:
                d -= sampled_values

        # reassign weights of any categories completely used up amongst
        # remaining weights
        sum_of_weights = sum([weights[index] for index in range(len(weights))
                             if datasets[index] != {}])
        sample_sizes = [0 if datasets[ind] == {} else
                        unused + weights[ind]*overflow_sum/sum_of_weights
                        for ind, unused in enumerate(unassigned_values)]

        # If there are any categories needing at least 1 extra value: re-assign
        if sum([1 for sample_size in sample_sizes if sample_size > 1]) > 0:
            continue
        else:  # Add any needed to the values with the highest unassigned
            needed = desired_sample_size - len(results)
            indexes = list(range(len(sample_sizes)))
            indexes.sort(key=sample_sizes.__getitem__, reverse=True)
            for i in range(needed):
                try:
                    results |= set(sample(datasets[indexes[i]], k=1))
                except ValueError:
                    raise ValueError("The desired_sample_size is too large for"
                                     " the categories provided")

    return results
```